# What is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

My code throwing java.lang.ClassCastException exception error, Why this error will get?. I am using com.android.internal.telephony API's. i.e You can find classes I am using here Call.java`<http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java>`, CallManger.java `<http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java.html>` I have created a Subclaas of Call.java like this:

```
    public class MyCall extends Call{   

        CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance(); 
        Phone.State state;
        Connection c;
         Phone mDefaultPhone;
         private final ArrayList<Connection> emptyConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();    
         MyCall ringingCall;     

        @Override
        public List<Connection> getConnections() {          
            state = cm.getState();      
            ringingCall = (MyCall) cm.getRingingCalls();
            System.out.println("**inside getConnections="+ringingCall);     
            if ( ringingCall != null && !ringingCall.isIdle()) {
                System.out.println("**call is not null***");
                return ((MyCall) ringingCall).getConnections();
            }      
            else
            {
                System.out.println("**list is  null***");
                return emptyConnections;
            }       
        }

        @Override
        public Phone getPhone() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void hangup() throws CallStateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isMultiparty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public Connection
        getEarliestConnection() {
            System.out.println("inside EarliestConnection"); 
            List l;
            long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            Connection c;
            Connection earliest = null;

            l = getConnections();

            if (l == null) {
                return null;
            }else if ( l.size() == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            System.out.println("value of connection is=="+l); 
            for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
                c = (Connection) l.get(i);
                long t;

                t = c.getCreateTime();

                if (t < time) {
                    earliest = c;
                    time = t;
                }
            }

        return earliest;
    }
}
```

I called CallManger.java like this in my own class

```
CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();
```

My another class is CallUpdate, it should give me a OutgoingCall states (i.e other side phone is Busy, Power-off, not-reachable etc.) The code is like this:

```
public class CallUpdate {   

    Call myCall = new MyCall();
    Connection myConn = new MyConnection();
    CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();

        public Object getCallFailedString(){

           myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
           System.out.println("myConn is  ******"+myConn);
           System.out.println("myCall is  ******"+myCall);  

           if(myConn == null){
                System.out.println("myConn is null ******");
                return null;
           }                
          else
            {
               Connection.DisconnectCause cause = myConn.getDisconnectCause();                       
               System.out.println("myconn is not null ******"+cause);   


                switch(cause){

                 case BUSY :
                   System.out.println("inside busy");
                 break;

                 case NUMBER_UNREACHABLE :
                    System.out.println("inside un-reachable");
                 break;

                case POWER_OFF :
                   System.out.println("inside power off");
                 break;  
              }
       }
    return myConn;
 }
```

I called this class in BroadCastReceiver(). But i am getting connection is null. My code is not getting inside else part. So that I added some code in getConnection method of MyCall class like this:

```
public List<Connection> getConnections() {      


     state = cm.getState();     
     ringingCall = (MyCall) cm.getRingingCalls();
         System.out.println("**inside getConnections="+ringingCall);        
          if ( ringingCall != null && !ringingCall.isIdle()) {
            System.out.println("**call is not null***");
            return ((MyCall) ringingCall).getConnections();
        }      
        else
        {
            System.out.println("**list is  null***");
            return emptyConnections;
        }   
    }
```

But I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: on Line:
   `ringingCall = (MyCall) cm.getRingingCalls();`
And also on `l = getConnection();` 
  How to solve this ??
Thx in advance.

Comment: Can anybody give me a correct answer ??!!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below

`List<MyCall> ringingCall = cm.getRingingCalls();`

I believe your `cm.getRingingCalls();` returning `ArrayList` of `Call` / `MyCall`

Answer (score 1):

`getRingingCalls` returns a `List<Call>` i.e. a list of `Call` objects. You're trying to cast it to a single `MyCall`, instead of a `List`, so you get a `ClassCastException`.

You need to correct your type to a `List`:

```
List<MyCall> ringingCall;
ringingCall = cm.getRingingCalls();
```

or, use the first element in the list:

```
MyCall ringingCall;
if(!cm.getRingingCalls().isEmpty()){
    ringingCall = cm.getRingingCalls().get(0);
}
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer but I am not yet all getting inside if :(

Comment: I tried it like: if(!cm.getRingingCalls().isEmpty()){
          
          System.out.println("inside if****");
          ringingCall = (MyCall) cm.getRingingCalls().get(0);
          System.out.println("**call is not null***");
             System.out.println("value of call"+ringingCall);
              return ((MyCall) ringingCall).getConnections();
          
         }   But i am not getting value of call statement